# Why the code doesn't break at the breakpoint in code blocks

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks, breakpoints

I followed the instruction from this video to run the code line by line:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CGH9Z19dS8

However, after I pressed F8, it just ran without going to the breakpoint(I couldn't see the yellow triangle). In addition, I also tried "attach to process", and it was the same.

Did I miss anything?(btw, there are multiple files in my project, but I guess that won't be the problem, right? cuz I could do this easily in VS studio. Perhaps, I am not that familiar with codeblocks)

Thanks for help!

If you are interested, this is the debugger log:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Release
Adding source dir: C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\
Adding file: C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\bin\Release\lattice_boltzmann.exe
Changing directory to: C:/Users/liuca_000/Documents/Lattice_Boltzmann_code/lattice_boltzmann/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.3.2-3;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\liuca_000\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\x64;.;\
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args C:/Users/liuca_000/Documents/Lattice_Boltzmann_code/lattice_boltzmann/bin/Release/lattice_boltzmann.exe
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Reading symbols from C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\bin\Release\lattice_boltzmann.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 16672
[Inferior 1 (process 16672) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Compiled with optimization? The code may be completely eliminated.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Ensure that the binary is compiled with debugging symbols (-g flag)

Comment: If the compiler can prove that the code can be replaced by some better code resulting in the same end result, it is legal for the compiler to remove code. That means, your breakpoint may never be hit, because it doesn't exist. watch [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2)

Comment: @stefan do you know how to quickly make it compile with breakpoints? because I am in windows, and I am not familiar cmd in windows.

Comment: @Cancan No idea, I don't use Windows for development.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you have had marked `-g` compiler option the problem may be spaces in path to the project file. Moving to place with no spaces in path solved the problem in my case.
See that: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces

Comment: Now I see that this is not an answer to the problem.

Comment: You're god! I've come here from Google and that was exactly the source of my problem!

Answer (score 3):

I think this part of your log says why:

> (no debugging symbols found)

build a debug version of your code - no optimisation, debug symbols included or built and try again.

Comment: Could you please give me a brief instruction how to change this quickly?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I should have done this in Linux, damn........ Do you know how to do this in windows?

Comment: What compiler are you using? You just have to look in the documentation.

Comment: I use GNU GCC compiler in Codeblocks

Comment: Thank all you guys!! I suddenly found that option "producing dubuging symbol -g"

Answer (score 1):

Spent quite a while working through this today trying:

- "Make sure using "debug" instead of "release"
- "No spaces in directory names"
- "-g ticked, -s unticked"
- "download a nightly"

None worked until, I figured I had been making a very novice mistake unfamiliar with the IDE and to debug so it stops at the break points you have to run with the red arrow not the green one. So anyone as silly as me hopefully this helps! xD

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found a solution that is the wrong solution and likely
to have adverse consequences. (Apologies if I am mistaken)

Your were unable to set breakpoints because your build contained no debugging
information (as you now know); and the build contained no debugging information
because you were trying to debug a Release build and not a Debug build.

You can see this in the build log:

> Adding file: C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\bin\Release\lattice_boltzmann.exe

and also:

> Reading symbols from C:\Users\liuca_000\Documents\Lattice_Boltzmann_code\lattice_boltzmann\bin\Release\lattice_boltzmann.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

The executable generated by a Release build will be `<project_dir>\bin\Release` (as it is), and the executable
from a Debug build will be in `<project_dir>\bin\Debug`

It appears that you have "solved" the problem by going to **Build Options** -> **Compiler flags** and ticking
the checkbox **Produce debugging symbols**.

But if you go back there and look at the tree control at the left of the window I expect you
will see:

- lattice_boltzmann

  - Debug
  - Release

with **Release** selected. That means you have now configured your **Release** build
to contain debugging information. You don't want that because:-

- Although you will now get debugging symbols in the executable and the debugger will be able to use them, the Release build is still configured with high optimisation by default (as it should be) and you are very likely to find that the behaviour of the debugger is at times strangely puzzling, because the optimized object code doesn't always properly match up with the source code.
- Your Release executable will be vastly inflated in size by the debugging information.

What you should have done is simply to ensure that the build you tried to debug *was*
a Debug build. To do that:

- Navigate from the top menu bar **Build** -> **Select Target**
- Uncheck **Release**. Check **Debug**

Then **Rebuild** the project (i.e. clean and build) and you will be able to debug it
properly. Code::Blocks default options for a Debug build are perfectly fine.

Don't forget to go back and remove the `-g` option from the **Release** configuration.